# Reverse polarity of 90 VDC motor with 2 foot switches

Tags: dc-motor, wiring, diagram, reverse-polarity

I am building a tool where I need to change the direction of the 90 VDC gear reduction motor with two foot switches.

Power is coming from a motor controller with variable speed. Terminal 4 and 5 have 90 VDC across them.

Motor has green, white and black wire, black and white to terminal 4 and 5 drive the motor fine, reverse the terminal and the motor runs in reverse direction.

I have 2 foot switches that have NO, NC, COM terminals on them.

Is there a simple way I can wire this motor to not run when neither switch is pressed, and run in either direction based on which switch you push?

Sorry for the non-technical description, I'm not a electrical guy, but a mechanical guy.

Comment: Do you have a manual for the motor controller?  Is it a standard (eg. KB) type?

Comment: What is the electrical rating or part number for the foot pedals?

Comment: As a mechanical guy, do you think your geared motor system will be just fine if you suddenly reverse its direction from full-speed forward to full-speed backward?

Comment: You might need a relay or two for this.